# Applying SSL to one page ONLY using htacess file

Tags: file, .htaccess, url, ssl, https

I have a webpage I need secured. However, I can **only** apply SSL to one, specific page. Since it is irrelevant to the discussion, I will not explain why this is the case.

I keep seeing the code below in different discussions and forums:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} somefolder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/somefolder/$1 [R,L]
```

While this works great for directories, it does not work for individual pages. Is there any way I could modify this to work for one page?

Answer (score 0):

change somefolder to file.php or equivalent should be all that is required. Then in the rule change /somefolder/$1 to file.php as well.